# Equal height table cells with a canvas inside: padding bug?

Tags: html, css, canvas

We have a fix set of CSS rules, but when we modify the HTML markup to include a canvas, a weird padding appears on the neighboring cell. Here is the CSS:

```
.wrap{
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.left{
    width: 100px;
    display: table-cell; 
    background-color: #0f0;
}
.right{
    background-color: #f00;
    display: table-cell;     
}
```

**Normal case:**

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJbTX/407/). Note the position of the text in the red cell: top, aligned with the top of the cell.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left">
            Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Canvas case:**

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJbTX/408/). We swapped the Lorem text in the left cell for a 90x90 canvas. See how the text on the red cell is now aligned with the bottom of the canvas and a padding is applied to the cell.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left">
            <canvas width='90px' height='90x'></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question:** Could you explain why this padding appears on the left cell, and if this is an expected behavior? Also, could you propose a solution that gets rid of this 'bug'?

Comment: As a side mark: When you want a content in the middle of an container, then you dont need padding. Use line-height and in this you put your height of your container.

Comment: This works for repositioning text when you know the height of your container. In this case, the height of the container is fluid and the part that needs repositioning could be a block instead of the Lorem text, so line-height would not allow to properly reposition the block. Furthermore, this does not explain the padding's presence when another cell has a canvas element.